# How to create mask using k means clustering?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, k-means, mask

I am using k means clustering on an image. I am finding 2 or 3 regions via k-means. Now I want to create a mask for each region so that I can separate them in my original image.
Following is the code I am using currently.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
 
%matplotlib inline
 
# Read in the image
image = cv2.imread('/content/istockphoto-1201224719-612x612.jpg')
 
# Change color to RGB (from BGR)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
pixel_vals = image.reshape((-1,3))
 
# Convert to float type
pixel_vals = np.float32(pixel_vals)
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 0.85)
 
# then perform k-means clustering wit h number of clusters defined as 3
#also random centres are initially choosed for k-means clustering
k = 2
retval, labels, centers = cv2.kmeans(pixel_vals, k, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
 
# convert data into 8-bit values
centers = np.uint8(centers)
segmented_data = centers[labels.flatten()]
 
# reshape data into the original image dimensions
segmented_image = segmented_data.reshape((image.shape))
plt.imshow(segmented_image)
```

Following is the image

[image]

Following is the output of the above image using k-means clustering (k=2)

[image]

**How can I create a mask for that yellow part to segment it from original?**

Comment: What's the problem with your output? Do you want to segment the shadows too?

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70603461/is-there-any-function-or-method-to-display-clusters-of-mage-after-k-means-image/70616126#70616126

Comment: No No , I want to create a mask  of all the clusters so that I can extract that ring part only from the background.

Comment: pick the right color space to make clusters make sense. it's all about distance, and how dimensions are scaled. you might wanna look at the saturation channel of the picture in HSL space -- if you choose two clusters, you get two, which are roughly background and foreground. your foreground turns out to be anything that isn't white.

Comment: Can you please help me with  the code!

Comment: @DanishBansal You mean a binary mask from each cluster?

Comment: Yes I am asking the same